# Cannot read property of undefined @ViewChild not working Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm having a bit of trouble I cant seem to figure out why my `@ViewChild` isnt working..

Basically I want to call a function in one component from another component so in my `sidebar` component I have a function called `sendData()` and I want to be able to call that from a button click in my `header` component so what Ive done is..

**Sidebar component**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';

import * as _ from 'lodash';


@Component({
   selector: 'app-sidebar',
   templateUrl: './sidebar.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sidebar.component.scss']
})
export class SidebarComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {

constructor(
    private contenfulService: ContentfulService,
    private userService: UserService
) { }

ngOnInit() {

}

sendData(){
    ...do something
}
}
```

**header.component.ts**

```
 import { Component, OnInit, Input, ViewChild, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
 import { UserService } from '../../../user.service';
 import { SidebarComponent } from '../sidebar/sidebar.component';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-program-header',
   templateUrl: './program-header.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./program-header.component.scss']
 })

 export class ProgramHeaderComponent implements OnInit {
 @ViewChild(SidebarComponent) sidebar;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
 }
```

**header.component.html**

```
<div (click)="sidebar.sendData()"></div>
```

but it isnt working Im getting this error in the console...

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'sendData' of undefined

*I have removed code for brevity, so please let me know if there is more information you need*

Im not sure what the problem is?

**EDIT**

Or if anyone knows another way to call a function from a seperate component let me know

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: where is function `goToWeek` defined? And how is it been invoked?

Comment: @Pengyy Sorry see updated question, I put in the wrong function name

Comment: can you post entire header component's template?

Comment: @Pengyy please see updated question

Comment: Post the full header.component.html with the sidebar.

Comment: @bc1105 Please see updated question, not sure why you would need to see the full header component html its a single div with a click event on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ViewChild` is expected to be used to get target element from current component's view(template) which matches the selector.

But according to your comment above, it seems there is no `app-sidebar` placed in your `header.component.html`, so `ViewChild` is not able to get a valid element which results in your current error.

The solution should be place `app-sidebar` at least once.

```
<app-sidebar></app-sidebar>
<div (click)="sidebar.sendData()"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

If header and sidebar components are siblings, you can not pass data between them directly.  Take a look at ‘Output’ and ‘Input’ from angular.  Alternatively, you can use a Service to  pass data between components. Check out services and observables.

```
<parent>
    <app-program-header>
    </app-program-header>
    <app-sidebar>
    </app-sidebar>
</parent>
```

Comment: I agree. Here is the official guideline: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to this conversation, I have been squirreled off on a couple of occasions chasing what seemed to be the lack of a functioning `@ViewChild` when the cause was the `@ViewChild` referencing a component in a module that was not being imported.  The "cannot read property of undefined" can become extremely misleading and may not be related to `@ViewChild` at all; be sure to check your imports first.

Answer (score 0):

In my case - it was the import from `"@shared"` which has caused this issue. You have to pay attention, that the component you are using the `@ViewChild` component reference is not in the same module with same shorthand path. If it is, import the `@ViewChild` component from

> 'shared/components/sidebar/sidebar.component'

and not from `'@shared'`

Answer (score 0):

You can always name the component using a # symbol.

HTML template:

```
<app-sidebar #sidebar1></app-sidebar>
```

TS code:

```
@ViewChild('sidebar1') sidebar: any;
```

You can import the type of your component instead of 'any'.

Hope this helps ;-)